# “Have at its centre”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I’m watching a documentary, and one sentence (in bold) confuses me.

> George V was not only a king but also an emperor. Shortly after his coronation, he and his queen empress travelled to India to receive the homage of their imperial subjects. **The British Empire had at its centre, India.** The Raj was the jewel in the crown, but the crown had never been. Queen Victoria had never gone, nor had King Edward VII. Here at last, the newly-crowned king George V wanted to go to India, and he did because that’s what the old imperial tradition was.

What does it mean, and what is the the grammatical structure of this sentence?

Comment: Rephrase it as "The British Empire had **India** at its centre." Just that *India* is moved to the end to draw attention to it. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammatical term for this kind of construction is "*postponement*". *The Cambridge Dictionary of English Grammar* (266) has this extract in its entry on *postposition*:

> **Postponement of a syntactic constituent**
>
> *Postposition* in English grammar is the delayed appearance of a phrase
>   or clause, so that it occupies a non-canonical position in the syntax.
>   ...
>
> *Postposition* is often strategic, designed to enhance information
>   delivery. ... The postpositioning of direct objects ... adds end
>   weight to them. The device also prepares them for further thematic
>   development in subsequent sentences, instead of being embedded in
>   mid-sentence.

So, by using postpostment the writer makes an unusual syntactic choice in order to give greater prominence to the word *India*.

As to the meaning, *center* can refer to the central geographical location of India within the British Empire - if the world is conceived as extending from America in the west to Asia in the east. But *center* can also be understood to mean that India was the most important colony of the Empire and its greatest focus.

Comment: It’s a very clear and illuminating  answer, thank you very much!